# django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixtures: no such table: pages_page__old

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

When I try to run: `python3 manage.py createdb`
after I add my password I get an error, after the superuser create successfully. and the finish of the following error is :

```py
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixtures: no such table: pages_page__old
```

The full error :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: pages_page__old

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mezzanine/core/management/commands/createdb.py", line 61, in handle
    func()
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/mezzanine/core/management/commands/createdb.py", line 109, in create_pages
    call_command("loaddata", "mezzanine_required.json")
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 131, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 69, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 115, in loaddata
    connection.check_constraints(table_names=table_names)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 276, in check_constraints
    cursor.execute(
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/martaf/Travail_insPYration/shop/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 326, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixtures: no such table: pages_page__old
```